# Ionic list-item bottom margin

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have a ion-list, that has a opened state which changes the class to a different background color:

```
.opened .item-content{
   background-color: #c4c4c4 !important;
}
```

The result shows a small white margin below the list item. Is there a way to remove it? (Note, I also use option-buttons and their colors in that small margin when I am swiping the item, regardless of the background color of the item)

[**Ionic Play**](http://play.ionic.io/app/12da98736cb3)

Comment: Can you create a demo? http://play.ionic.io

Comment: @ManojKumar http://play.ionic.io/app/12da98736cb3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small white space is caused by the parent element's background color. You can override it with same background color:

```
.opened.item {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
}
```

Set item's height to increment by 1px for covering up the space.

```
.item {
  height: 101px;
}
```

[**Updated Ionic**](http://play.ionic.io/app/8fd45819e609)

Comment: Thank you, but that fixed the "opened" issue, if you swipe the unopened ones, one can see the colors in that little margin.

Comment: That worked, added a new class (item-collection) instead of "item" as it was changing other lists! Thank you!

Comment: @Wigiri No problem! :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an issue with `collection-repeat`. Using `ng-repeat` solves the issue.

http://play.ionic.io/app/f1d2eb83ee03

```
<ion-item ng-class="{'opened item-content':item.state}" class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="item in news" href="#/feed/{{item.source}}/{{item.link}}/{{item.title}}" ng-click="openNews(item, 'open')">
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, problem is I have over 500 items and ng-repeat get extremely slow